# How do I add TFS tracking to a GIT-TFS cloned repo?

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I am currently working as follows :

- We have a TFS branch - let's call it TFS-Master.
- We have a git-tfs cloned repository of TFS-Master.
- I have pushed this repository to github.

Up until now, people have been working from my github repository quite happily. I've been syncing us up with the TFS repo when required, and all has been well.

However, for whatever reason, other people would like the honour of keeping the git repo up to date with TFS and vice versa.

How do I add the git-tfs tracking (well, whatever you might call the ability to push / pull from tfs) to a repository cloned off of the github repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps entirely, but....

The homepage of [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki) points to: http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/how-to-establish-git-central-repository-for-working-against-tfs-with-git-tfs-bridge/ for an automated guide.

If you take a look in the comments, there is someone talking about a 2-way synchronisation.

**UPDATE (Taken from comments)**

https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/bootstrap.md is the specific command required.

Comment: Nice. This is exactly what I was after and more. Annoying I missed that link so long ago :)

Comment: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki/Bootstrap is technically the command I believe I was after as a side note ;)

Comment: @gregpakes fyi the documentation has moved here: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/bootstrap.md